Trouble cloning a git repo using ssh with a secondary (non default) public key
I am trying to access an old git repo on BitBucket via SSH.
The SSH key has not changed on either the client or BitBucket, but cloning the repo is failing.
git clone git@bitbucket.org:william_ferguson_au/lexathon-server.git
Cloning into 'lexathon-server'...
The requested repository either does not exist or you do not have access. If you believe this repository exists and you have access, make sure you're authenticated.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Variations on the command as suggested by responders:
git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.org/william_ferguson_au/lexathon-server.git
Cloning into 'lexathon-server'...
The requested repository either does not exist or you do not have access. If you believe this repository exists and you have access, make sure you're authenticated.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.


git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.org:william_ferguson_au/lexathon-server.git
Cloning into 'lexathon-server'...
ssh: Could not resolve hostname bitbucket.org:william_ferguson_au: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.



I have tried creating a new SSH key and uploading it to BitBucket as suggested by https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/git-clone-fails-when-cloning-via-ssh-879243661.html, but it had no effect.
Can someone point me in the right direction please.
NB the repository exist and I have the correct access rights.
How do I know this ? Because I have this repository cloned elsewhere on this same machine and I am able to push to it.

Did you set any proxy or insteadof related options in gitconfig?

No. No gitconfig proxy or insteadof settings

OK, so using
set GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -vvv
git clone git@<bitbucket URL>:<project key>/<repository slug>.git

I can see that it is authenticating with BitBucket using the default ssh public key (.ssh/id_rsa), but it then fails to find that repo because the user for the default public key doesn't have access to that repo.
What I needed to do was to append "-" plus the project key to the BitBucket URL. ie
git clone git@<bitbucket URL>-<project key>:<project key>/<repository slug>.git

This finds the correct public key to authenticate with for the BB repository. Authenticate succeeds and the repo is found and cloned.

Like the others have said, you don't need the ssh -vvv, but if you're going to use the ssh:// format then you need to use git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.org/william_ferguson_au/lexathon-server.git (with the ssh://, and with a slash between bitbucket.org and william_ferguson_au instead of the colon).
You can also use git clone git@bitbucket.org:william_ferguson_au/lexathon-server.git (without the ssh://, and with a colon between bitbucket.org and william_ferguson_au) instead. Both will work, but you can only use one at a time.

I have tried all variations of those, None of them work.

What exactly does it say to make you think it doesn't work? (Note that I'm asking for exact output. Please copy and paste - this is not the place to summarize.)

You should only need to pass this command.
git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.org:william_ferguson_au/lexathon-server.git
No reason to run ssh -vvv git ...  When you do that, you're passing arguments to ssh to look up the host name git, which the error is telling you it doesn't understand the arguments passed and that host doesn't exist.
If the ssh key is expired or no longer works, you'll receive a 401 error from bitbucket, otherwise, the clone will begin.

I prepending 'ssh -vvv' just to provide some info for this question. 'git clone ..' on its own fails with : "fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists." Both of which are true

The short version of that command, ssh -vvv git is saying "ssh very verbosely to host git with arguments ..."
Try just git clone ...?

I prepending 'ssh -vvv' just to provide some info for this question. 'git clone ..' on its own fails with : "fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists." Both of which are true.

The linked page says the command must be
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git clone ssh://git@<bitbucket URL>:<bitbucket port>/<project key>/<repository slug>.git

not ssh -vvv git.
Upd. For w32 (cmd) the commands should be
set GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv"
git clone ssh://git@<bitbucket URL>:<bitbucket port>/<project key>/<repository slug>.git
set GIT_SSH_COMMAND=

Upd2. For ssh:// URL the syntax must be ssh://git@bitbucket.org/william_ferguson_au/lexathon-server.git but not ssh://git@bitbucket.org:william_ferguson_au/lexathon-server.git. Note the difference between : and /. For scp-like URL the syntax is git@bitbucket.org:william_ferguson_au/lexathon-server.git. For ssh:// URL : may be used for a non-standard port: ssh://git@bitbucket.org:22/william_ferguson_au/lexathon-server.git. For scp-like URL a non-standard port cannot be used.
See the docs.

Yes. But it also for Linux, not Windows. Once you have set that env variable as you have wriiten above and attempt to execute it, then it just fails with ""ssh -vvv"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

NB I was prepending 'ssh -vvv' just to provide some info for this question. 'git clone ..' on its own fails with : "fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists." Both of which are true. See updated question.

I updated answer for w32 (cmd).

ssh -vvv cannot be prepended to git clone. It could be ssh -vvv git@<bitbucket URL> but certainly not git clone.

Noted, thank you. I have updated the question with the output form the git client.

@William See Upd2.

Question updated plus I found a solution. NB I was not able to craft the solution to work at all using a ssh:// url.
